# Dynamically creating and expanding std::tuple into parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic

I'm writing a plugin for software written in C++, here's a snippet where the plugin is defined:

```cpp
extern "C"
irods::ms_table_entry* plugin_factory() {

    // The number of msParam_t* arguments that it will accept
    int numArguments = 2;

    irods::ms_table_entry* msvc = new irods::ms_table_entry(numArguments); 

    msvc->add_operation(
        "my_microservice",
        std::function<int(msParam_t*, msParam_t*, ruleExecInfo_t*)>(MyMicroservice)
    ); 

    return msvc;
}
```

I'd like to be able to use `numArguments` to dynamically generate the `std::function<int(msParam_t*, msParam_t*, ruleExecInfo_t*)>` parameter pack. Where `numArguments` represents the number of `msParam_t*` arguments.

I'm not a C++ expert (especially with templating), so [after some research](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2015/12/05/modern-c-variadic-template-parameters-and-tuples/) I've found that this *might* be possible by implementing the following:

- std::tuple
- std::tuple_cat
- std::index_sequence
- std::make_integer_sequence

But I don't really know how to get started on implementing this. The examples I found were hard to understand, and I couldn't manage to translate them into my own needs. Can anyone provide tips, short examples, or references on how this might work? Any info is greatly appreciated!

Comment: is `numArgument` known at compile time?

Comment: Its not possible to do this dynamically, because that would involve code generation, but you could generate it statically or a set statically. What is the type of add_operation?

Comment: @DavideSpataro - No, `numArgument` would be defined at runtime.

Comment: @user1937198 - Here are the docs for add_operation https://fossies.org/dox/irods-4.2.0/classirods_1_1api__entry.html#af358e9a9156f4410ab758b076d8cabc9

Comment: Does it represent the number of arguments of `MyMicroservice`? If it does it is known at compile time.

Comment: You can't do something at runtime what should have been done already at compile-time... `std::make_index_sequence` needs parameter known at compile-time to generate at that time appropriate `std::integer_sequence` if you don't know the value at compile time you are doomed to create all possible options that you wish to support and then at runtime choose one from previously pre-compiled types...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the following is exactly what you're asking but I think that what you want is being able to generate the right template parameters for the `std::function` based on the number of arguments that your `MyMicroservice` takes which is stored into the `numParameters` variable.

If that is the case you can simply omit writing them at all and use `decltype`and let the compiler write them for you.

```
int myMicroservice1(int a,int b, int c){
    return a+b+c;
}

int myMicroservice2(int a,int b, int c,int d){
    return a*b*c-d;
}

int myMicroservice3(int a,int b, int c,int d,int e, int f){
    return a*b*c+e+f;
}


template<typename... types_t>
void add_operation(const std::string & _op, std::function< int(types_t...)> _f ){

}   

int main() {
    add_operation("blabla",std::function<decltype(myMicroservice1)>(myMicroservice1));
    add_operation("blabla",std::function<decltype(myMicroservice2)>(myMicroservice2));
    add_operation("blabla",std::function<decltype(myMicroservice3)>(myMicroservice3));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just realized that even if I could dynamically build the parameter pack from a runtime integer, `MyMicroservice` arguments would still be static. Requiring a function defined for each set of differing arguments. I appreciate your answer, it helped me identify the flaws in my idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
struct toFunc;

template<typename...T>
struct toFunc<std::tuple<T...>>
{
    using type = std::function<void(T...)>;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    using t = std::tuple<int, int, int>;
    using func = toFunc<t>::type;
    auto f = func([](int a, int b, int c){std::cout << a << b << c << std::endl;});
    f(1, 2, 3);
  return 0;
}
```

toFunc typetrait will convert your tuple to a function type. not sure if you want that. If you want to call with the argument you maybe need to look for 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

or you can use this implementation:

```
namespace detail
{
            template <unsigned int N>
            struct for_each_t_idx
            {
                template <template<std::size_t> class Functor, typename... ArgsT>
                static void exec(const std::tuple<ArgsT...>& t, Functor<N> func)
                {
                    for_each_t_idx<N - 1>::exec(t, func);
                    func<N - 1>(t);
                }
            };

            template <>
            struct for_each_t_idx<0>
            {
                template <template<std::size_t> class Functor, typename... ArgsT>
                static void exec(const std::tuple<ArgsT...>& t, Functor<0> func)
                {
                }
            };
}

    template <template<std::size_t> class Functor, typename... ArgsT>
    void for_each_idx(const std::tuple<ArgsT...>& t, Functor<sizeof...(ArgsT)> func)
    {
        detail::for_each_t_idx<sizeof...(ArgsT)>::exec(t, func);
    }
```

This will call a given function for each element in a the tuple.